# Public report/telemetry API

Tags: javascript, spam, api, rest

I want to implement a telemetry data sender into my electron app. The API which I want to connect to is public. So any crash reports or any other data from the user is sent to it. The problem is how do I secure the API to prevent spam reports?

For example VS Code is collecting telemetry data from the user and it's sending those data to a collecting REST API. How does Microsoft prevent spam reports?

The structure is the following

Electron App -> User Data -> (How to prevent spam?) API Server -> Database

Thanks

Comment: It would appear that a form of authentication is the standard control.

Comment: But how does a form authentication works in a software which is public to everyone. Look at vscode's telemetry data sending. I can't find any type of code in the code base of vscode that will generate an fixed ID for the user. So Microsoft ist handling the post request for there API in a way that they can validate them to prevent spam reports.

Comment: Don't think in terms of that kind of authentication. You don't need to authenticate the specific user or node, but rather you need to authenticate the submission.

Comment: Ah I see, you mean to specify the form of sending? Maybe some sort of generated hash, which the server can validate?

Comment: That's the sort of thing. Digital Signing, HMAC, shared secrets, etc.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot. Just one last question. How would you implement such a mechanism in an electron app? The source code is not protected in electron and can easily be extracted. It would be not smart if I place a public key into my source files. How would you handle this?

Comment: That's now more of a programming question. Think about asking over at Stack Overflow